# Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using **AFNetworking** to get the data from server using post methods in iOS but i am getting

```
 Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1607abf0> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { status code: 400, headers {
        "Content-Length" = 54;
        "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        Date = "Wed, 02 Nov 2016 13:24:20 GMT";
    } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400), com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c68746d 6c3e3c74 69746c65 3e457272 6f722034 30302028 42616420 52657175 65737429 2121313c 2f746974 6c653e3c 2f68746d 6c3e>, NSUnderlyingError=0x14fde930 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1607abf0> { URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send } { status code: 400, headers {
        "Content-Length" = 54;
        "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        Date = "Wed, 02 Nov 2016 13:24:20 GMT";
    } }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<3c68746d 6c3e3c74 69746c65 3e457272 6f722034 30302028 42616420 52657175 65737429 2121313c 2f746974 6c653e3c 2f68746d 6c3e>}}}
```

**Here is my code :**

```
 NSDictionary *homeAddressDict = @{ @"message_from" : MessagesFrom, @"type" : typeOfMessage, @"time" : forDate, @"message" : sendMessges };
        NSDictionary *params = @{@"data" : homeAddressDict, @"to":tofcmTokenID};
    NSLog(@"%@",params);
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];


   // Content-type = "text/html";


   [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"text/plain"];

   // manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];

   // "Content-Type" = "text/html;
    //NSString *key = [self urlEncode:@"key=AIzaSyB6w3yutLPH2Tbr6HoQyynHssxUHVRt-Vc"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"key=AIzaSyBWr7ThxdSbyrJQjYHrQ2AvN9nUblh0ZGQ" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                  serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

     manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/plain"];
   // manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


    [manager POST:@"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Server groupssss JSON is: %@", responseObject);
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.response.allHeaderFields);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", operation.response.allHeaderFields);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

Comment: The crucial error information is: **unacceptable content-type: text/html**. And don't post your actual API key!

Answer (score 0):

You can set 'manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes' by using 'AFHTTPResponseSerializer', where you can set content type.